# How to disable adding relative path in PyCharm?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

I want to execute tests but I can not since PyCharm is adding relative path of file executed.

I have such directory structure:

```
src
src/wage.py
src/test/__init__.py
src/test/wage.py
```

When I put `src/test/wage.py` it imports `src/test/wage.py` instead `src/wage.py` since `sys.path` is `['src/test', 'src']` not `['src']`.

How to disable adding  `src/test` at all or at first place in PyCharm - since it impossible to import correct `wage.py`?

Comment: In the run configuration there is the option.

Comment: What is name of this option since it can be visible but not working?

Answer (score 3):

In PyCharm:
Run -> Edit Configurations

Under Configurations tab you change the "Working directory"
from src/test/ to src